# regex expression (using 'replace' operator for powershell)

Tags: replace

Was wondering if someone could help?. I have the following string and wish to ONLY get out the '2.90GHz'

Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 0 @ **2.90GHz**

I have managed to use the following **('([0-9].[0-9][0-9]GHz$)')** to get me the '2.90Ghz'. However when i try to 'negate' the value it doesn't understand it.

i.e **('^[([0-9].[0-9][0-9]GHz$)]')** - what am i doing wrong ???? Any help would be appreciated

Abdul

Answer (score 0):

Don't know where you are getting this string, but **Win32_Processor** have *MaxClockSpeed* or *CurrentClockSpeed* attributes that you can round using Math and string formating. But, answering your question:

**$var.Split('@')[-1]** should do, then trim any spaces if needed.